# Create GitHub service connection using azure rest api giving error

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create GitHub service connection using azure Devops rest api -

In postman I put following Json Body-

```
{
   "name": "release-1",
   "type": "github",
   "url": "https://github.com",
   "authorization": {
   "scheme": "PersonalAccessToken",
   "parameters": {
   "accessToken": "<Github_Personal_Access_Token>"
  }
 }
}
```

This Creates service connection but It gives error when I open service connection in UI and try to verify but if I edit and replace with same Github token In UI then it works. seems like its not taking token I am providing in Json body -

[image]

I also see information here on this ongoing issue - https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2019/12/28/workaround-azure-github-pat/

I want to automate GitHub service connection creation.

How to create GitHub service connection using Azure Devops rest api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create GitHub service connection using Azure Devops rest api ?

Are you creating this GitHub service connection?

[image]

If so, you should use [EndPoints-Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#create-service-endpoint) API and your Json Body can follow this format:

```
{
    "authorization": {
        "scheme": "Token",
        "parameters": {"AccessToken": "YourGitHubPAT"}
    },
    "data": {},
    "description": "",
    "name": "YourServiceConnectionName",
    "serviceEndpointProjectReferences": [{
        "description": "",
        "name": "YourServiceConnectionName",
        "projectReference": {
            "id": "YourProjectID",
            "name": "YourProjectName"
        }
    }],
    "type": "github",
    "url": "https://github.com",
    "isShared": false
}
```

We should enter the value of `YourGitHubPAT`, `YourServiceConnectionName`(twice in two points), `YourProjectID` and `YourProjectName` with your own values to make the body work. We can get `YourProjectID` via [Projects-List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

After running that in PostMan, I can verify it successfully without issues. I guess your issue may have something to do with your parameters. Use

```
"authorization": {
    "scheme": "Token",
    "parameters": {"AccessToken": "<Github_Personal_Access_Token>"}
},
```

Instead of

```
"authorization": {
   "scheme": "PersonalAccessToken",
   "parameters": {"accessToken": "<Github_Personal_Access_Token>"}
```

**Update about how to enable grant access to all pipelines:**

Dislike other elements like Token, Name and Description, `Grant Access Permissions to all pipelines` option is managed by another API.

API to enable this option:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{YourOrganizationName}/{YourProjectName}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/{YourEndPointID}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Body:

```
{
    "resource": {
        "id": "YourEndPointID",
        "type": "endpoint",
        "name": ""
    },
    "pipelines": [],
    "allPipelines": {
        "authorized": true,
        "authorizedBy": null,
        "authorizedOn": null
    }
}
```

Note: We need to enter EnterPointID in URL and Body. (Twice!)

In PostMan, you should use **PATCH** method and **application/json** type. The `YourEndPointID` is `ServiceConnectionID`, you can get this value from EndPoints-Create API's response.

So normally to create a service connection with "Grant Access to All..." enabled, we should run Endpoints-Create first and then run the second API to enable this option.

(And this is the same behavior in Web Portal. When we click `Verify and Save` button in web browser, it actually also calls these two APIs to complete the process.)

Comment: How can I also enable security option - grant access to all pipelines options in json body shown In above image?

Comment: @megha This option is managed by another API, you can check my update in answer for more details.